# Structure for database to track motor racing results in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

As a way of learning something new I decided to try to create a site to track motor racing results in C# .Net Core MVC with a code first database using EF.

However straight out of the gate I'm wondering I'm taking the wrong approach altogether with my data structure.

I have models for Nation and Season, that are retty straight-forward (ID, Name and, for Season, a collection of Races). However the way I've done the Race and Driver models is a little more complex. I want to track a) where the Race is, b) what season it is part of and c) which driver finished where.

Each race will have 26 drivers competing.

Here's the model I created for race:

```
    public class Race
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SeasonID { get; set; }
        public Season Season { get; set; }
        public int NationID { get; set; }
        public Nation Nation { get; set; }

        public int Driver1ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Driver1ID")]
        public virtual Driver Driver1 { get; set; }

        public int Driver2ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Driver2ID")]
        public virtual Driver Driver2 { get; set; }

        public int Driver3ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Driver3ID")]
        public virtual Driver Driver3 { get; set; }

        // And so on, I'll spare you the rest, it goes all the way down to 26...

        public int Driver26ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Driver26ID")]
        public virtual Driver Driver26 { get; set; }


    }
```

And here's the model for Driver:

```
public class Driver
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int NationID { get; set; }
        public Nation Nation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Race> P1 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Race> P2 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Race> P3 { get; set; }
// Again I'll save you the whole thing, it goes down to 26...
        public ICollection<Race> P26 { get; set; }
    }
```

In order to make that work I figured I had to set the relationship in the Context class like so...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Race>().HasOne(r => r.Driver1).WithMany(d => d.P1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Race>().HasOne(r => r.Driver2).WithMany(d => d.P2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Race>().HasOne(r => r.Driver3).WithMany(d => d.P3);
// Snip down to 26 again...
            modelBuilder.Entity<Race>().HasOne(r => r.Driver26).WithMany(d => d.P26);
        }
```

But when I try and update the database I get an error that this structure would cause "cycles or multiple cascade paths" which really doesn't sound too good. I know that it's possible to set Cascade Delete off, but the error message is making me think I'm really on the wrong path here in the first place... Am I totally barking up the wrong tree here?

Any help or advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: You should not have 26 separate navigation properties.  Just use Many-to-Many relationship between Race and Driver, probably using an explicit linking entity called something like RaceParticipant or somesuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would model it something like this (leaving out stuff like season, nation):

```
public class Race
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RaceParticipation> Participants { get; set; }
 }

public class Driver
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RaceParticipation> Races { get; set; }
}

public class RaceParticipation
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public Race Race {get;set;}
    public Driver Driver {get;set;}
    // maybe information like this:
    public int StartingPosition {get;set;}
    public int FinalPosition {get;set;}
}
```

Things such as the fact, that every race has exactly 26 participants, should IMO be part of your business logic, not the database design. This is probably something that might change sometime in the future (i.e. when you would like to have different number of participants per race). So having that logic in code seems to be more flexible.